# How to write defaults value from a file as bytes?

Tags: terminal, defaults

How to save content of a file into via defaults in such a way that they are handled as -data type?

In fact, I am searching for a command line alternative for this obj-c code:

```
NSData *data = // ... get the data
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"mykey"];
```

When I call `defaults read` on that key I get:

```
% defaults read mydomain mykey
{length = 400, bytes = 0xdcf2dbbb cb4343d7 ec4324ae 1234de18 ... 289f4567 ec4324ae }
```

Later in an obj-c app, the data are read using:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [userDefaults dataForKey:@"mykey"];
```

Even I have no idea what the right approach to mimic setting the key is, I presume it might be something like:

```
% FILEDATA=... # read abc.xyz into a variable
% defaults write mydomain mykey -data "$FILEDATA" # save into user data
```

Comment: Does the `-data` option not exactly do this? You can use `od` to convert binary to hex.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it properly. As per the manual (https://ss64.com/osx/defaults.html), `-data       Allows the user to specify a bunch of raw data bytes as the value for the given preference key.  The data must be provided in hexadecimal.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `defaults` *command* in **Terminal**, the following is a *simple example* of writing a *key* containing *data* as its *value* to a **PLIST** *file*:

```
% data='5468697320697320612064756D6D7920656E74727921'
% defaults write ~/Desktop/my.dummy.plist 'foobar' -data "$data"
% defaults read ~/Desktop/my.dummy.plist foobar           
{length = 22, bytes = 0x5468697320697320612064756d6d7920656e74727921}
% /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print foobar' ~/Desktop/my.dummy.plist   
This is a dummy entry!
%
```

To convert the contents of a *file* to *hex data* suitable for use with the `defaults` *command*, use the following:

```
% data="$(xxd -p '/path/to/file' | tr -d '\n')"
```

Or in place of `"$data"` in the example `defaults` *command*, replace it with:

```
"$(xxd -p '/path/to/file' | tr -d '\n')"
```

Example:

```
defaults write ~/Desktop/my.dummy.plist 'foobar' -data "$(xxd -p '/path/to/file' | tr -d '\n')"
```

**Notes:**

This *syntax* also works:

```
data='<5468697320697320612064756D6D7920656E74727921>'
defaults write ~/Desktop/my.dummy.plist 'foobar' "$data"
```

Note that `<` and `>` are used as part of `data` and the `-data` *option* was **not** used for the *value type* of the target *key* in the `defaults` *command*.

The *hex data* used in the *example* was created using the following *command* to convert the *text string* to *hex data*:

```
% xxd -p -u <<< 'This is a dummy entry!'
5468697320697320612064756D6D7920656E747279210A
%
```

The use of the `-u` *option* with the `xxd` *command* is not absolutely necessary. I just like to see *upper case hex data* in the *example*.

After writing the *data* to a **PLIST** *file* in the first example further above, I use `PlistBuddy` to read the *value* of the target *key*.  Keep in mind that in this *simple example* the *value* of `foobar` is just a *text string* and it outputs the converted *hex data* as shown, however, if the *value* of the *data* in the target *key* is e.g. a binary **PLIST** *file* itself or other binary *data*, the *output* isn't going to be pretty.